# Проблема с указателями на окна SFML

Tags: c++, указатели, sfml

Я пробую создать класс окна со статичными функциями(чтобы не создавать экземпляр окна) и пробую обратиться к этому классу из main-а, однако я не понимаю, как мне обратиться к указателю и инициализировать окно

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class cWindow {
public:
    sf::RenderWindow *pWindow;
    int initializate(int width, int height) {
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Ukushu Project");
        pWindow = &window;
        return 0;
    }
    static void terminate();
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow *mWindow = cWindow.pWindow;

    while (mWindow->isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mWindow->pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                mWindow->close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: с статических функций нельзя обращаться к простым переменным класса, которые доступные только, когда есть экземпляр класса. Вывод - либо делайте все статическим, либо создайте экземпляр класса (объект). Можно конечно и синглтон сделать, но зачем?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То есть, мне стоит убрать статик у всех функций и просто создать экземпляр класса?

Comment: я думаю, это самое нормальное решение. А сам класс можно прям на стеке создать и будет абсолютно нормально.

Comment: Ошибки компилятора исчезли, но теперь мне выдает в консоль большое значение в качестве ошибки, а само окно не появляется. Теперь я, видимо, туплю, и понимаю, как мне передать ему указатель на окно

Comment: ну как бы initializate сохраняет ссылку на локальную переменную, а потом пытается ее использовать. Это практически всегда выстрел в ухо. Почему бы sf::RenderWindow window не сделать частью класса? или если нужен указатель, тогда new/умные указатели